# Cancel of requests through saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise, redux-saga

We provide a drop down option at the top..let's say it has options A B C.
Whenever user changes the drop down option, a saga gets triggered which makes around 10 different webapi calls.( A map of calls which get executed in parallel)

We use takeLatest helper in saga watcher.
So if user  immediately changes the dropdown from A to B., Only calls made via B are consumed at client end as takeLatest aborts saga that got triggered by A.

Now , the problem is though only B's calls are consumed, all the A's promise calls that are in pending, also run to completion.
Only saga (because of A) gets aborted but not the api calls.
We can see that in network tab.
So, if user changes between A B C rather quickly, we would have around 30-40 calls to server.
All of those run to completion though we are just interested in completion of last 10 calls.
If we see in chrome dev tools, last 10 calls are in queue or stalled until the above ones are done.
Isn't there a way to propagate the cancellation from saga(takeLatest level)to axios and there by cancelling promises.
Axios docs say about cancellation and tokens but I'm not clear about how to propagate cancel in a redux -Saga  and axios environment.
How to initiate cancel from saga to axios?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Basically it's a how to solve the problem kind of question.
The existing code does not throw any error.
I want an approach or code to cancel axios promise

Comment: @Sandeep, can you please elaborate below solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
const cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source()
try {
  yield all([
    call(axios.get, "/api/1", { cancelToken: cancelSource.token }),
    call(axios.get, "/api/2", { cancelToken: cancelSource.token }),
    /// ...
  ])
} finally {
  if (yield cancelled()) {
    yield call(cancelSource.cancel)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, where is cancelled() defined? or Is it a pre-defined function of redux-saga?

Comment: @olanchuy It's defined by redux-saga. https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#cancelled

Comment: @apaatsio have you done this in "export default function* rootSaga() {"  & used fetch

Comment: @apaatsio  But how do I verify that the request is cancelled? In class/functional component, we'll verify in catch block as `if (axios.isCancel(e))`. In Saga `if (yield cancelled())` is enough??

Answer (score 5):

If someone is interested in a working solution to this exact problem, I am creator of redux saga library addon specifically to those kind of problems - https://github.com/klis87/redux-saga-requests

It does those kind of things automatically for you - if a saga in cancelled, request is aborted automatically, so you dont even need to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer helped me, however, I had to use this call

```html
yield call(cancelSource.cancel)
```